# Appwarp create multiplayer screen

Tags: android, libgdx, appwarp

I am new in `Appwarp` and also in multiplayer gaming. `Superjumper` is a great tutorial and its methodology seems incredible, but I do not know, how to build `MultiplayerGameScreen.java` from my own single player game.

Can you please give me maybe a step-by-step instruction or guidelines, how to make this file?

Comment: I did not know of `appwarp` before seeing your question - but maybe [this tutorial](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-multiplayer-libgdx-tutorial/) will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiplayerGameScreen.java is a game specific class. All the AppWarp related functionalities are implemented in the WarpController.java class which you can find [here](https://github.com/SauravGShephertz/libgdxMultiplayerSuperJumper/tree/master/superjumper/src/appwarp). MultiplayerGameScreen.java is just calling the required methods from WarpController.java.

To convert the single player game to multiplayer, you can use the following steps:

1. All the players who needs to play together must join same [room](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-api-reference/#joinroom)
2. Once game starts, if player needs to send its information to other players, you can use either [sendUpdatePeers](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-api-reference/#sendupdatepeers) or [sendChat](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-api-reference/#sendchat) as per the game requirement
3. Once a player sends update then server sends notification to other players which you can receive in the corresponding callbacks such as onChatReceived in case of sendChat
4. Once you get the notification, you can update your game UI accordingly

You can always write to us on support@shephertz.com or on our [forum](http://forum.shephertz.com/) in case of any problem.

Comment: Thanks for this short description, makes this much more clear!